# How do you append a svg image to a rect element of another svg image?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I trying to append a svg image to a `rect` element in a svg image, using d3 and trying

```
chart.selectAll("rect.bar")
  .each(function(datum, index) {
    d3.select(this)
      .append("svg:image")
        // ..some attributes
  });
```

This adds `<image>` to the dom, but the image does not show. I've also tried using jquery to select `this` in the `.each` block, which adds it to the dom, but also doesn't show.

For jquery I've added it with

```
$(this).after("<svg:image xlink:href='/images/image.svg' x='20' y='20' width='20' height='20'/>");
```

with the `svg` and `xlink` namespaces in the `html` element

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I've been able to create one image per `rect.bar` with `.selectAll`, but I want to create more based on the `datum` value.

Comment: Attributes I had were fine, as they were used in my .selectAll attempt, which worked.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use jquery to select the parent element so that the image does not get put *inside* the `rect.bar` element, but alongside it. Code here:

```
chart.selectAll("rect.bar")
  .each(function(datum, index) {
    var rectBar = $(this).parent()[0]; // Needs parent object, otherwise it will append inside rect
    var num = 4;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      d3.select(rectBar)
        .append("svg:image")
          // ...some attributes
    }
  });
```

Also `.parent()` by itself didn't work. I needed to explicitly do `.parent()[0]`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it matters to you but I believe you can do this without the use of jquery.  Mike Bostock's "[D3 Workshop](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/)" presentation shows how to properly select and append elements within the DOM.

Once you can select any element, you can append any SVG drawing (e.g. a rect, circle, text, etc. and even external images).  To control the placement of the image that is appended, I believe you can simply use the "dx" and "dy" coordinate offset controllers.

In the example, "[Multiple D3 Pie Charts Mixed With Common HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2141479)", I first create multiple SVG canvases based on HTML DIV locations on the HTML page.  I then place the bars at specific locations on the SVG canvas.  Then I append and place the legend bullets at different points on the same SVG canvas.  Finally, I append the and place the legend text on the same SVG canvas at different locations.  In each case, I use the dx and dy coordinate controllers to control the placement of the objects.

I hope this helps,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
chart.selectAll("rect.bar")
  .each(function(datum, index) {
    $(this).append("<img href='http://www.mysite.com/images/test.jpg' />")
        // ..some attributes
  });
```

Comment: Actually, this works, but also my code works (was added inside the rect.bar element, which I didn't check). The issue is that I can't get the syntax right for adding svg images using d3/jquery or otherwise. I'll update the question.

Comment: Good, I did that precautionary. Its important if are getting required elements